# PHP: Validate date from user input

Tags: php, validation, exception, if-statement

in my application the user inputs a date (if he wants with hours and minutes specification) which gets saved in a variable like this:

```
$userdate = new dateTime($dateraw);
```

Now I want to check if the input is valid, the following opportunities should be possible:

> 20.01.2015 12:00
>   2015-01-20 12:00

And it is also very important to check if the users submitted a valid day and month.

> valid day = a number but not over 31
>   valid month = a number but not over 12

I tried something like that

```
if ($userdate->format('%a') > 31 ) {
echo "Your day input is not valid.";
}
```

Comment: Easy fix would be to wrap new DateTime() in a try...catch as this will catch anything that cannot be parsed correctly. It just wouldn't give the fine detail of what they typed wrong, e.g.: month > 12 or days > 31.

Comment: Personally, I'm wondering why you'd want to allow multiple formats in the first place. There are a lot of caveats when it comes to using date formats that are not immediately obvious without reading the documentation. Pick one format, it will make your life easier, be less susceptible to error, and doesn't confuse your users.

Comment: Any `DateTime` object will always be a valid date. You will need to validate the parts before creating a date time object.

Comment: Either use datepicker kind of JS to avoid direct user input, so validation will be easy. Moreover, user can't input directly. Second option is use separate input fields for month, date, year hour etc. So can be validated very easily.